# Splitting a feature collection by system index in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: gis, google-earth-engine

I am trying to export a large feature collection from GEE. I realize that the Python API allows for this more easily than the Java does, but given a time constraint on my research, I'd like to see if I can extract the feature collection in pieces and then append the separate CSV files once exported.

I tried to use a filtering function to perform the task, one that I've seen used before with image collections. Here is a mini example of what I am trying to do

Given a feature collection of 10 spatial points called "points" I tried to create a new feature collection that includes only the first five points:

var points_chunk1 = points.filter(ee.Filter.rangeContains('system:index', 0, 5));

When I execute this function, I receive the following error: "An internal server error has occurred"

I am not sure why this code is not executing as expected. If you know more than I do about this issue, please advise on alternative approaches to splitting my sample, or on where the error in my code lurks.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

system:index is actually ID given by GEE for the feature and it's not supposed to be used like index in an array. I think JS should be enough to export a large featurecollection but there is a way to do what you want to do without relying on system:index as that might not be consistent.

First, it would be a good idea to know the number of features you are dealing with. This is because generally when you use **size().getInfo()** for large feature collections, the UI can freeze and sometimes the tab becomes unresponsive. Here I have defined chunks and collectionSize. It should be defined in client side as we want to do **Export** within the loop which is not possible in server size loops. Within the loop, you can simply creating a subset of feature starting from different points by converting the features to list and changing the subset back to feature collection.

```
var chunk = 1000;
var collectionSize = 10000
for (var i = 0; i<collectionSize;i=i+chunk){
  var subset = ee.FeatureCollection(fc.toList(chunk, i));
  Export.table.toAsset(subset, "description", "/asset/id")
}
```